# Python loop through a text file reading data

Tags: python, loops

I am new to python, and although I am sure this might be a trivial question, I have spent my day trying to solve this in different ways.  I have a file containing data that looks like this:

```
<string>
<integer>
<N1>
<N2>
data
data
...
<string>
<integer>
<N3>
<N4>
data
data
...
```

And that extends a number of times... I need to read the "data" which for the first set (between the first and second ) contains a number N1 of X points, a number N2 of Y points and a number N1*N2 of Z points. If I had only one set of data I already know how to read all the data, then read the value N1, N2, then slice it into X, Y and Z, reshape it and use it... but if my file contains more than one sets of data, how do I read only from one string until the next one, and then repeat the same operation for the next set, and again until I reach the end of the file?
I tried defining a function like:

```
def dat_fun():
    with open("inpfile.txt", "r") as ifile:
        for line in ifile:
            if isinstance('line', str) or (not line):
                break
            for line in ifile:
                yield line
```

but is not working, I get arrays with no data on them.  Any comments will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Is this an xml file, if it is you could use python's built in xml parsing module.

Comment: Its a plain text file. @johnthexiii. I want all the sets, some files contain two sets, some more.  From each set of data I have to use the X, Y and Z to create some plots, which I've been successful in doing if I manually create independent files with only one set of "<string> \n <integer>\n <N1>\n <N2> data ...." per file.  I want to be able to read one set until the next <string> is reached (and use its data), then read trough the next set of data until the next <string> is reached, and so on until the end of the file. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

**All** lines are instances of `str`, so you break out on the first line. Remove that test, and test for an empty line by stripping away whitespace first:

```
def dat_fun():
    with open("inpfile.txt", "r") as ifile:
        for line in ifile:
            if not line.strip():
                break
            yield line
```

I don't think you need to break at an empty line, really; the `for` loop ends on its own at the end of the file.

If your lines contain other sorts of data, you'd need to do the conversion yourself, coming *from* string.

Comment: So the fist test to see if its a string doesn't differentiate the floats (which are the "data" type) or the integers (which are the N1, N2, N3...) from the 'alphabetical character' strings?  Because my data are numbers, and I want to get arrays of data, lets say data1 for the data between the first and second <string>, data2 for the data between the second and third <string> and so on until the end of the file. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

With structured data like this, I'd suggest just reading what you need. For example:

```
with open("inpfile.txt", "r") as ifile:
    first_string = ifile.readline().strip() # Is this the name of the data set?
    first_integer = int(ifile.readline()) # You haven't told us what this is, either
    n_one = int(ifile.readline())
    n_two = int(ifile.readline())

    x_vals = []
    y_vals = []
    z_vals = []

    for index in range(n_one):
         x_vals.append(ifile.readline().strip())
    for index in range(n_two):
         y_vals.append(ifile.readline().strip())
    for index in range(n_one*n_two):
         z_vals.append(ifile.readline().strip())
```

You can turn this into a dataset generating function by adding a loop and yielding the values:

```
with open("inpfile.txt", "r") as ifile:
    while True:
        first_string = ifile.readline().strip() # Is this the name of the data set?
        if first_string == '':
            break
        first_integer = int(ifile.readline()) # You haven't told us what this is, either
        n_one = int(ifile.readline())
        n_two = int(ifile.readline())

        x_vals = []
        y_vals = []
        z_vals = []

        for index in range(n_one):
            x_vals.append(ifile.readline().strip())
        for index in range(n_two):
            y_vals.append(ifile.readline().strip())
        for index in range(n_one*n_two):
            z_vals.append(ifile.readline().strip())
        yield (x_vals, y_vals, z_vals) # and the first string and integer if you need those
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I think this will be the way of doing it if I was interested only in the first set of data, but I would like to go through the whole file being able put into different arrays every set of data (lets say into data1 the data between first and second <string>, into data2 the data between second and third <string> and so on until the end of the file). The "first_integer" is an integer that has to do more with the process that generates that particular set of data, so I am not interested on that one, only on the n_one and n_two...

Comment: but I think once I understand how to put into arrays the data between strings it will be easier for me to figure out how to read the n_one, n_two and so on as integers. Thanks.

Comment: And yes, the first string (and each string) is the name of the corresponding data set.

Answer (score 1):

```
def dat_fun():
    with open("inpfile.txt", "r") as ifile:
        for line in ifile:
            if isinstance('line', str) or (not line): # 'line' is always a str, and so is the line itself
                break 
            for line in ifile:
                yield line
```

Change this to:

```
def dat_fun():
    with open("inpfile.txt", "r") as ifile:
        for line in ifile:
            if not line:
                break
            yield line
```

Comment: `not line` is not likely to ever be `True`; all but the last line will have a newline, and even then the last line wouldn't be empty.